# $\Big(D\in X\;\land\; D\notin (X-Y)\Big) \implies D\in Y$. Why?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $D \in X$. Why is this statement true? $$\Big(D\in X \;\land D\notin (X-Y)\Big) \implies D\in Y$$

I know that $D\in (X-Y) \equiv D\in X \land D\notin Y,\;$ but claiming $D\notin (X-Y) \implies D\in Y$ is like claiming "The cookie jar isn't in the kitchen therefore it must be in my room".

What am I missing?

Comment: Do we know that $D \in X$?

Comment: Yes @JimmyK4542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D \in X$ and $D \not\in Y$, then by definition $D \in (X-Y)$.

But since we know that $D \not\in (X-Y)$ we must have either $D \not\in X$ or $D \in Y$.

Since you said you know that $D \in X$, then we are left with $D \in Y$.

The statement $D \not\in (X-Y) \iff D \in Y$ is like saying "Since the cookie jar is not in any of the other rooms in the house, it must be in my room" (Assuming the cookie jar is in the house).

Comment: Is this statement alone true: $D\notin (X-Y) \implies D\notin X \lor D\in Y$?

Comment: Yes it is. In fact, the implication can go in both directions.

Answer (score 6):

$$d \notin (X-Y) \iff \lnot(d \in X \land d\notin Y) \iff (d\notin X \lor d\in Y)$$ Since we know that $d\in X$, we know that $$\lnot \lnot (d \in X) \iff \lnot(d\notin X)$$ which, together with the first premise, it follows that  $d \in Y$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessarily true, if $D\notin X$.

Of course, in the context from which you take it, you already assume that $D\in X$, so it is necessarily the case that $D\in Y$.

Comment: Oh I understand now completely. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: At some point I thought I understood (but didn't). btw, I've opened a new question because the thread got a bit big ..

Comment: What? No, that comment thread wasn't big at all. When you reach 20 comments you can start talking about "not small".

Answer (score 1):

Since you already answered that we are assuming $D \in X$, then suppose $D \not \in (X - Y)$.  Note that $X - Y = X \cap Y^{c}$.

So we have $D \not \in X - Y \implies D \not \in X \cap Y^{c}$.  But $D \in X$, and $X = (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Y^{c})$, so if $D \in X$, then $D$ must be in one of the two sets $(X \cap Y)$ or $(X \cap Y^{c})$.

Since we already ruled out that $D \in (X \cap Y^{c})$, then it must be that $D \in (X \cap Y)$, which implies $D \in Y$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$D \notin (X-Y)$ if and only if $\neg (D \in X \wedge D \notin Y)$. Because of [*De Morgan's laws*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) 
$$\neg (D \in X \wedge D \notin Y) \iff D \notin X \vee D \in Y$$

If we suppose that $D\in X$, than $D \in Y$ must be true.